# how to resolve TypeError: 'Manager' object is not callable in django python

Tags: python, django

here's my code

from django.db import models

Trying to run this command(already imported Album class succesfully)-- `newAlbum=Album.objects(name="1",Artist=newArtist).save()`

I am getting error:

```
TypeError: 'Manager' object is not callable'
```

Comment: Did you get to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Either creating an instance an saving it:

```
newAlbum = Album(name="1", Artist=newArtist).save()
```

or using the models manager create method

```
newAlbum = Album.objects.create(name="1", Artist=newArtist)
```

Read more in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects).

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If so, I would appreciate it if you mark this answer as accepted.